# Why shows error "import nltk"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk

I was trying to build web crawler using python and I'v got following error when it executed.

```
import sys
import math
import re
from collections import OrderedDict, defaultdict
import os
import nltk //This line shows error
import pickle
from xml.dom import minidom
from xml.dom import EMPTY_NAMESPACE
import nltk  //This line shows error
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
import time`enter code here`
```

How to overcome this problem?

Comment: pip install nltk in command prompt did you try that

Comment: 1) Check that module is installed 2) Check that you have correct PYTHONPATH

Comment: You will get errors on those lines because the comment symbol for Python is `#`, not `//`.

Comment: @cdarke I think those were just added for the question.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan:  how do you know?  I have seen stranger things on this site.  The OP is not showing the exact error message.

Comment: @cdarke Admittedly it's possible but I think it would be an amazing accident to generate errors just highlighting lines where you were getting errors.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan:  it was a tongue in cheek attempt to tell the OP to shown the error message.  He could have put a different comment next to that line using `//` because he has come from C++ or Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can check whether already nltk you have installed or not. 
Otherwise you can download from here.

> [NLTK download link](http://www.nltk.org/install.html)

In ubuntu, you can try followng one:

```
sudo apt-get install python-nltk
```

Answer (score 2):

try to install the package in your computer.

ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install python-nltk
```

Answer (score 0):

use...

```
nltk.download('punkt')
```

...after you load nltk. You should be fine.