# Error in importing NLTK :

Tags: python, import, nltk

Error as on screen : 
On import of nltk :

> ImportError: cannot import name raise_unorderable_types

I've already checked these :

1. [Why shows error "import nltk"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270361/why-shows-error-import-nltk)
   already.
2. reinstalled nltk using : pip2 install nltk --upgrade
3. when I try command line level nltk commands like nltk.download , it still throws the same error
4. Unable to resolve why, I checked dist_packages for python2.7 , it has nltk in it.
5. Checked by trying to import Other packages in dist_packages like gensim, It works.

Python version : 2.7.6
IPython Shell Version : 1.2.1

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-b06499430ee0> in <module>()
----> 1 import nltk

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/__init__.py in <module>()
    103 # Import top-level functionality into top-level namespace
    104 
--> 105 from collocations import *
    106 from decorators import decorator, memoize
    107 from featstruct import *

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/collocations.py in <module>()
     34 from operator import itemgetter as _itemgetter
     35 
---> 36 from nltk.probability import FreqDist
     37 from nltk.util import ingrams
     38 from nltk.metrics import ContingencyMeasures, BigramAssocMeasures, TrigramAssocMeasures

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/probability.py in <module>()
     46 from operator import itemgetter
     47 from itertools import imap, islice
---> 48 from collections import defaultdict
     49 
     50 ##//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/collections.py in <module>()
     20 from six import text_type
     21 
---> 22 from nltk.internals import slice_bounds, raise_unorderable_types
     23 from nltk.compat import python_2_unicode_compatible
     24 

ImportError: cannot import name raise_unorderable_types
```

Comment: Do you have a file called `tokenizer.py`?

Comment: Please copy-paste the traceback as text (use a code block to format it); images are not searchable, and unreadable by text-readers.

Comment: @Evert Thank you , I have added the traceback lines as well

Comment: @Colin : These are the only tokenizers I could find.
 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/html5lib/tokenizer.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/html5lib/tokenizer.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dns/tokenizer.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dns/tokenizer.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/_tokenizer.py

Comment: Do you have any files in your project whose names might conflict with `NLTK`?

Comment: @Colin: The same issue is happening in python shell as well. Opened a new python shell and did import , It caused the same issue.

I found this function in another installation of nltk on a different PC , I added this to it and it seems to work now. But no idea why it was not there in a fresh installation .

def raise_unorderable_types(ordering, a, b):
    raise TypeError("unorderable types: %s() %s %s()" % (type(a).__name__, ordering, type(b).__name__))

Comment: What files (in particular, Python files) are in your current working directory?

Comment: have you tried to uninstall it, and reinstall it with `conda` (if you have the anaconda ditribution) ?

Comment: @Evert These are the files I have :ActualURL1.csv  
corpus
corpusmaker.py
models
output.log
TopicModel.py 
all_corpus 
corpus_keys 
labels.json     
models_old1  removed_dataset_files

Comment: I don't have the anaconda distribution , @Jacquot, I'll get it and try if it will handle it.

Comment: created a token.py with my code and received the same error. After deleting it, works ok